# sencha navigation view overlapping on home listview

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, navigationview

I am using sencha navigation view in my sencha application .
my bug scenario 
I have list view with images on home screen first time it's load 20 record then scroll to down record will be increase by 20 on every scroll when i click on any image and redirect to another view like image detail view or profile view and come back to home on pressing back button all the images overlapped.

please help i am trying to solve this bug before 10 day's but not get success :- before overlapping

1) I am using navigation view it's extend with "Ext.dataview.DataView" and there is using 
useComponents: true,
defaultType: 'productlistitem'

2) In 'productlistitem' extend with 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem' In this view I am using update method witch set the image and other component data and also using dynamically method for image width , height .

below you can check my all views code

A) Home.js

```
Ext.define('demo.view.home.Home', {

    extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',

    requires: [
        'demo.view.product.ListItem',
        'demo.view.layout.ColumnLayout'
    ],

    xtype: 'home',

    config: {

        scrollable: true,
        plugins: {
            xclass: 'demo.plugin.DataViewPaging', // Reference plugin by class
            autoPaging: true
        },

        autoDestroy: true,

        store: 'LookStore',

        margin:'2 0',

        useComponents: true,

        defaultType: 'productlistitem',

        cls: 'wow-home',

        layout: {
            type: 'column',
            columnCount: 2,
            columnWidth: 160
        }
    }
});
```

B) ListItem.js

```
var listItemData=[];
Ext.define('demo.view.product.ListItem', {

    extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',

    requires: ['demo.view.product.Item'],

    xtype: 'productlistitem',

    config: {
        padding: 2,
        zIndex:999,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'item'
        }]
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('initing the list item  ');
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        this.on('heightchange', 'recalculateHeight', me, {
            delegate: '> item'
        });
    },

    recalculateHeight: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.setHeight(me.innerElement.getHeight());
    },

    updateRecord: function(record) {
        if (!record) {
            return;
        }
        var me = this,
            item = me.down('item');
        me.callParent(arguments);
        if (item) {
            item.updateRecord(record, me.getDataview());
        }
        listItemData.push(item.id);
    }
});
```

c) Item.js

```
Ext.define('demo.view.product.Item', {

    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    xtype: 'item',

    requires: [
        'Ext.Carousel',
        'demo.view.product.ItemImage',
        'demo.view.product.UserInfo',
        'demo.view.product.InfoLabel'
    ],

    config: {
        record: null,

        baseCls: 'wow-item',
        showDescription: false,
        items: [{
                xtype: 'itemimage',
                width: '100%'
            }, {
                xtype: 'userinfo',
                height: 40,
                listeners: {
                    painted: function() {
                        if (!this.element.hasListener('tap')) {
                            this.element.on('tap', function(e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                var record = this.scope.up('item').getRecord();
                                if (!this.scope.getHandleListeners()) {
                                    if(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('main')[0].getActiveItem().xtype === "wardrobedrawer")
                                        demo.app.getController('ProductController').openProductDetail('', '', '', record);
                                    return;
                                }
                                if (record && !Ext.isEmpty(record.raw.product_id) && !Ext.isEmpty(record.raw.importer)) {
                                    var brandMerchantProducts = this.scope.up('brandmerchantproducts');
                                    if (brandMerchantProducts) {
                                        var currentTitle = demo.app.getController('HomeController').getMain().getActiveItem().config.title;
                                        var currentItem = this.scope.element.dom.textContent;
                                        if (currentTitle.toUpperCase() !== currentItem.toUpperCase()) {
                                            demo.app.getController('ProductController').showMerchantProducts(record);
                                        }
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    demo.app.getController('ProductController').showMerchantProducts(record);
                                } else {

                                    var list = this.scope.up('list');

                                    demo.app.getController('ProfileController').goToOtherUserProfile(list, null, null, record.get('merchantId'), e);
                                }
                            }, {
                                scope: this
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            {
                xtype: 'container',
                height: 40,
                margin:'1 0 0 0',
                name: 'infoContainer',
                layout:'hbox',
                defaults: {
                    xtype: 'infolabel',
                    flex: 1
                },
                items: [{
                    iconCls: 'icon-diamond',
                    text: '09',
                    itemId: 'wows',
                    listeners: {
                        painted: function() {
                            if (!this.element.hasListener('tap')) {
                                this.element.on('tap', function(e) {
                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                    var record = this.scope.up('item').getRecord();
                                    if (record.get('type') == 'product') {
                                        demo.app.getController('ProductController').wowOrUnwowHomeProduct(record, this.scope.up('item'));
                                    }
                                    if (record.get('type') === 'look') {
                                        demo.app.getController('ProductController').wowOrUnwowHomeLook(record, this.scope.up('item'));
                                    }

                                }, {
                                    scope: this
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    iconCls: 'icon-drawer',
                    text: '11',
                    itemId: 'lookOrAdd',
                    listeners: {
                        painted: function() {
                            if (!this.element.hasListener('tap')) {
                                this.element.on('tap', function(e) {
                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                    var record = this.scope.up('item').getRecord();
                                    if (record.get('type') == 'product') {
                                        demo.addedProductItem = this.scope.up('item');
                                        demo.app.getController('ProductController').addProduct(record);
                                    }
                                    if (record.get('type') === 'look') {
                                        demo.app.getController('ProductController').addHomeLook(record, this.scope.up('item'));
                                    }

                                }, {
                                    scope: this
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]

    },

    initialize: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.on('load', 'imageLoaded', me, {
            delegate: 'itemimage'
        });
    },

    imageLoaded: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.setHeight(me.element.getHeight());
    },

    updateRecord: function(item, dataview) {
        if (!item) {
            return;
        }
        if (dataview && dataview.config.showDescription) {

            this.setShowDescription(true);

        }
        var me = this;

        me.setRecord(item); 
        if (item) {

            var itemImage = this.down('itemimage'),
                images = item.get('images'),
                wows = item.get('wows') + '',
                adds = item.get('adds') + '',
                userInfo = this.down('userinfo');
            if (images && images.length) {
                itemImage.setSrc(images[0].original);
            }

            var type = item.get('type');
            var lookOrProduct = me.down('#lookOrAdd');
            var added = item.get('added');
            var icon;

            if (type === 'product') { 
                icon = 'icon-add-drawer';
                lookOrProduct.setIconCls(icon);
            } else {
                icon = added ? 'icon-counterlook' : 'icon-addlookbook';
                lookOrProduct.setIconCls(icon);
            } 
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(item.raw.product_id)) {
                userInfo.setAvatar('');
            } else { // USER

                var importer = item.get('importer');
                if (importer) {

                    var avatar = importer.avatar;
                    if (avatar) {
                        userInfo.setAvatar(avatar);
                    } else {
                        userInfo.setAvatar('resources/images/default/default_avatar.jpg');
                    }
                }
            } 
            me.down('#wows').setText(wows);

            if (!item.get('wowed')) {
                me.down('#wows').addCls('grayedout-cls');
            } else {
                me.down('#wows').removeCls('grayedout-cls');
            } 
            lookOrProduct.setText(adds);
            if (!item.get('added')) {
                lookOrProduct.addCls('grayedout-cls');
            } else {
                lookOrProduct.removeCls('grayedout-cls');
            }
            var infoContainer = this.down('container[name=infoContainer]');
            if (infoContainer && infoContainer.isHidden()) {
                infoContainer.show();
            } 
            var title = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('main')[0].getActiveItem().title;
            var storeId = this._record.stores[0].getStoreId();
            if (type === 'product' && !Ext.isDefined(title) && storeId !== 'WowedStore' && storeId !== 'SearchStore' && storeId !== 'BrandMerchatProducts') {
                var homeUrl = this._record.stores[0].getProxy().getUrl();
                if ((homeUrl === demo.model.Config.apiServerPath('home')) || (homeUrl === demo.model.Config.apiServerPath('home'))) {
                    var noOfProducts = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#productsInTheListId').length;
                    if (noOfProducts === 1) {
                        userInfo.setUsername(item);

                        if (me.getShowDescription()) {
                            infoContainer.hide();
                            userInfo.setAvatar('');
                            userInfo.setUsername(item);
                            userInfo.setHandleListeners(false);
                        }
                    } else {
                        userInfo.setUsername(item.get('author'));

                        if (me.getShowDescription()) {
                            infoContainer.hide();
                            userInfo.setAvatar('');
                            userInfo.setUsername(item.get('description'));
                            userInfo.setHandleListeners(false);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    userInfo.setUsername(item);

                    if (me.getShowDescription()) {
                        infoContainer.hide();
                        userInfo.setAvatar('');
                        userInfo.setUsername(item);
                        userInfo.setHandleListeners(false);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                userInfo.setUsername(item.get('author'));
                if (me.getShowDescription()) {
                    infoContainer.hide();
                    userInfo.setAvatar('');
                    userInfo.setUsername(item.get('description'));
                    userInfo.setHandleListeners(false);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    updateColorOfItem: function(item) {

        var me = this,
            lookOrProduct = me.down('#lookOrAdd');
        if (!item.get('wowed')) {
            me.down('#wows').addCls('grayedout-cls');
        } else {
            me.down('#wows').removeCls('grayedout-cls');
        }

        if (!item.get('added')) {
            lookOrProduct.addCls('grayedout-cls');
        } else {
            lookOrProduct.removeCls('grayedout-cls');
        }
    }
});
```

D) ItemImage.js

```
Ext.define('demo.view.product.ItemImage', {

    extend: 'Ext.Img',

    xtype: 'itemimage',

    config: {

    },

    onLoad: function(event) { 
        var me = this,
            width = me.getParent().element.getWidth(), // me.element.getWidth() should work but I have found that sometimes it gives a width of 0. Now I go with a width of the parent.
            imageObject = me.imageObject,
            naturalWidth = imageObject.width,
            naturalHeight = imageObject.height,
            naturalRatio = naturalHeight / naturalWidth,
            newHeight = naturalRatio * width;
        me.setHeight(newHeight);
        //Ext.ComponentQuery.query('productlistitem')[0].setHeight(newHeight+84);
        me.callParent(event);
    }

});
```

E) UserInfo.js

```
Ext.define('demo.view.product.UserInfo', {

    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    requires: ['Ext.Img'],

    xtype: 'userinfo',

    config: {
        avatar: null,
        username: null,
        baseCls: 'wow-user-info',
        handleListeners: true

    },

    applyAvatar: function(avatar) {

        if (Ext.isEmpty(avatar)) {
            return null;
        }
        return Ext.factory({
            src: avatar,
            cls: 'wow-avatar',
            docked: 'left'
        }, 'Ext.Img');
    },

    updateAvatar: function(newAvatar, oldAvatar) {

        if (newAvatar) {
            this.add(newAvatar);
        }
        if (oldAvatar) {
            oldAvatar.destroy();
        }
    },

    applyUsername: function(item) {
        if (Ext.isObject(item)) {
            var price_value = "",
                price_currency = "",
                itemName = "";

            if (Ext.isDefined(item.raw.price)) {
                if (Ext.isDefined(item.raw.price.value)) {
                    price_value = item.raw.price.value.toString();
                }
            }
            if (Ext.isDefined(item.raw.price)) {
                if (Ext.isDefined(item.raw.price.currency)) {
                    price_currency = item.raw.price.symbol;
                }
            }
            if (item.raw.description === null) {
                var item = item.data.author;
            } else {
                var item = item.raw.description;
            }
            item = item.toLowerCase();
            itemName = item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1);
            if (Ext.isDefined(price_currency) && Ext.isDefined(price_value) && (price_currency !== "") && (price_value !== "")) {
                itemName = '<div class="itemNames"><span style="font-size:0.9em" >' + price_currency.bold() + ' ' + price_value.bold() + '</span>' + " " + '<span style=" font-size:0.8em" class="itemName">' + itemName + '</span>' + '</div>';

            } else {
                itemName = '<div class="itemNames"><span style=" font-size:0.8em" class="itemName">' + itemName + '</span></div>';
            }
            return Ext.factory({
                html: itemName,
                xtype: 'component',
                cls: 'wow-username-product'
            });
        } else {
            return Ext.factory({
                html: item,
                xtype: 'component',
                cls: 'wow-username'
            });
        }
    },

    updateUsername: function(newUsername, oldUsername) {
        if (newUsername) {
            this.add(newUsername);
        }
        if (oldUsername) {
            oldUsername.destroy();
        }
    }

});
```

F) InfoLabel.js

```
Ext.define('demo.view.product.InfoLabel', {

    extend: 'Ext.Button',

    xtype: 'infolabel',

    config: {
        iconAlign: 'left',
        cls: 'wow-info-label'
    },
    initialize: function() {

        // Do nothing stopping unnecessary event listeners being added.
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like a timing problem on when your are loading your store or try to manipulate your view. Can you provide us a Sencha Fiddle or add some code to your question?

Comment: @Tarabass  my code is to wast have many views and many controllers need to test for same issue so i am not able to add code on sencha fiddle.
I also observe this is time problem for that what i need to do ...

Comment: Try to disable animation between views. Does it help?

Comment: @Baidaly bad luck I have disable animation between view but still overlapping occurring

Comment: Have you tried to updateLayout - http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-updateLayout ?

Comment: @Baidaly Please check  my all the code I have updated my question